# How do I make a directive with a property in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I don't understand how to make a component with a property. Can you see what's the matter?

I keep getting this error: "Can't bind to 'val' since it isn't a known native property"

// app.html

```
There should be a list of fruit here with a line after each one
<ul>
  <template ngFor let-fruit [ngForOf]="fruits">
    <li>{{fruit}}</li>
    <part [val]="5"></part>
  </template>
</ul>
```

and

part.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'part',
  templateUrl: 'app/part.html'
})
export class PartComponent { 
  // meaningless for now. I just want this thing 
  // to take a parameter
  val: number;
}
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kRzCSm?p=preview)

If I may be allowed to suggest, a plunk provided by the Angular team that demonstrates the most common features of the technology (like [these](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/) but in plunk form and even more basic) would be way more useful to me than [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html). If you know of such a thing, I'd be very grateful for the referral.

Comment: Answers below work.... tried working through it myself but was missing the `directives:[PartComponent]` part http://plnkr.co/edit/lFTSOu?p=preview also the cookbooks section of the documentation has some live samples for components with incoming values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need declare child directives in you main component. add `directives:[PartComponent]` to your `AppComponent`'s meta data. AND `@Input()` is needed for `val` property.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Input()` decorator is missing

```
export class PartComponent { 
  // meaningless for now. I just want this thing 
  // to take a parameter
  @Input() val: number;
}
```